# Blender Rendered viewport is different from the rendered image in Cycles

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, depth-of-field

I have this scene:
[image]
It's basically a bunch of particles that have an emission shader.
The camera is using depth of field and gives this results using the rendered viewport:

[image]

But When I render the image it gives me the foollowing result:

[image]

As You can see it's completely different from the viewport image.  The colours are way less bright and there is way more noise.
The samplings are both (Preview and Render) set to 200. And these are the depth of field settings:

[image]

And these are the render settings:

[image]

As you can see the viewport and the rendered image are completely different, is there a way I could make them the same? 
Am I Doing something wrong?

Comment: Try overlaying that image on top of some background (like black or something) or in the UV editor disable transparency channel from showing, maybe what you see is bug of preview image.

Comment: If you are trying to have emissive and transparent pixels, the viewer for the rendered image will not display them correctly Please read these related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824  and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34002/glow-effect-invisible-on-transparent-background/44137#44137 AND https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/65546/1853 AND https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67789/render-halo-material-with-tranparent-background/67792#67792